# Thread safe async file writе with FileIO.ReadTextAsync

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, async-await, win-universal-app

How I can use [FileIO.ReadTextAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readtextasync) in windows universal apps so that it will be thread safe? Because trying something similar like

```
lock(lockObject)
{
    var data = await ReadTextAsync(fileName);
}
```

but using `await` in `lock` is not supported =(.

Comment: Why do you need the `lock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SemaphoreSlim` and the `WaitAsync` method.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported because there are no (managed) threads during an I/O call, and the current method will be continued later, potentially on another thread.

Lock is a synchronous concept, and since you're serializing access already, can you just call `ReadText` instead of `ReadTextAsync`? Do you really benefit from async in your case?

Comment: Smart idea to just not use async. +1